# UserProfileInfo matching query does not exist Django

Tags: python, django

I need to have extra information about a person, more than the default `User` model provides. That's why I've created the `UserProfileInfo` model that's supposed to hold all this extra info, such as `house_number`, `phone_number`, `full_name`, and `community`.

Now, an instance of `UserProfileInfo` is created whenever a user registers. But when I run this route called `all_books` in `views.py`, I get an error: `UserProfileInfo matching query does not exist`.

Here's my `all_books` view:

```
def all_books(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context = {
            "books": Book.objects.all(),
            "request": request,
            "user_profile": UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user),
        }
    else:
        context = {
            "books": Book.objects.all(),
            "request": request,
            "user_profile": False,
        }
    
    if request.GET.get("context") == "mail_sent":
        context["mail_sent"] = True
    return render(request, 'main/all_books.html', context)
```

This error happens only when I've signed in, and not when I'm not signed in.
When I head over to the admin, I see that the profile has been created. But I don't understand why this isn't able to get that.

Comment: Does the profile created has as `user_id` column, the id of the corresponding user? Perhaps the record exists, but are these not properly linked.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It does show me in the admin that the user for a record in the UserProfileInfo is "testuser1", the same as the user I'm trying to login through.

Comment: Huh... Something's going on! I changed nothing, and now the error's not there.